# Formulario que hace submit al hacer click en cualquiera de sus input

Tags: javascript, html, login

Tengo un pequeño problema y es que tengo este formulario de login realizado con bootstrap y al querer tratar de ingresar los datos de logueo, este, al hacer click en cualquier parte del formulario, se ejecuta el jQuery, que en teoría, debería llamar únicamente al submit que se llama 'login'

```js
$(document).on('click','#login', function(){
  alert("entro");
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
        <title>Tickets</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Ingresar al sistema
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username">Usuario</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="**********">
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Iniciar sesión"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Estás usando id repetidos (id="login"), no es recomendable usarlo. En todo caso deseas si o si usarlo pues en el oyente click cambialo a submit: $(document).on('submit','#login', function(){...

Comment: @Omarsinho muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ya corregí el error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error es en esta linea:

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria- 
              labelledby="login-tab">
```

debes cambiarle el id="login" por otro. saludos